# My Local JavaScript file is not loaded in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have added a local javascript file with `<script type='text/javascript' src='Test.js'>` in my **index.html**, but when I run it with ng serve and go to `localhost:4200`, in my browser console I see this error:

> GET localhost:4200/Test.js 404 (Not Found) but I do have my file in
>   the same location that my index.html.

but angular 2 not loading or finding this. Please help me.

Comment: What error do you get...

Comment: GET http://localhost:4200/Test.js 404 (Not Found) I get this error.

Comment: Welcome to Stalk Overflow. Update that as part of your question before you get a wave of downvotes. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And when you get an answer that is acceptable to you, don't forget to mark it as so: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move your `Test.js` file to the assets folder. 
Then from `index.html`, point to that folder `<script type='text/javascript' src='./assets/Test.js' >`

WHY?
When you serve your app with `ng serve`, there's a structure set for it. If you want to see it, run `ng build`, you will see a `dist` folder being created.

Observe the assets folder gets move to that dist folder, and that's how the app expects it. So you are getting the not found error because from the server's perspective, there's no such file there.

When you make those changes and run `ng serve`, things should work and error should go away.

Hope this is of help.

Comment: If you could somehow decipher his question to a workable answer, would you be so kind to propose an edit to the question?

Comment: Of course @StephanBijzitter. I didn't know I could do that so I had requested on a comment to the OP to update his question.

Comment: Submitted edit suggestion @StephanBijzitter.

And you are welcome @VidhyaSagar!

Comment: @Juan But if i want to run the script file in a component html file. Is that possible ? Because now i don't get error and it doesnt recognize the script anymore.